# How can I avoid maximum recursion depth?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I'm trying to use a recursive function for the first time and I'm getting the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".

I'm initially trying to code Ahrens Moving Average. I found the code for this in another platform and I'm trying to write it in Python.

Here is the original code in another scripting lanuage :

```
    IF BarIndex < Period2 THEN
    AFRV2 = Seriesv2
    ELSE
    AFRV2 = AFRV2[1] + ((Seriesv2 - ((AFRV2[1] + AFRV2[Period2]) / 2)) / Period2)

# where [1] is the previous element
```

And here is my attempt:

```
def AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period):
    for index, rows in TimeSeries.iterrows():
        if index < period:
            AFRV2 = rows
        else:
            AFRV2 = AFRV2 + ((rows.iloc[-1] - ((AFRV2 + AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period)) / 2)) / period)
```

When calling this function with a DataFrame consisting of one column, I get the error message above.
As you probably can tell, I'm still in the learning process with Python and my question is if I'm using function recursion "correctly" or is the error due to other parts of my code?

Thank you for any help!

This is the 30 first elements of the DataFrame.

```
0   114.4050
1   114.9425
2   115.7075
3   114.5175
4   113.4825
5   114.3150
6   115.5950
7   116.0200
8   119.1650
9   129.3700
10  131.8000
11  131.7325
12  130.6075
13  131.0800
14  131.0575
15  131.2150
16  130.4275
17  129.8875
18  130.5400
19  131.1250
20  130.9675
21  130.2025
22  129.8875
23  129.8425
24  129.1225
25  126.4025
26  127.3000
27  128.3350
28  128.2225
29  128.7625
```

Comment: The problem size does not seem to get smaller in the recursive call. `AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period)` calls `AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period)`.

Comment: One red flag is as follows: when you call `AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period)`, it recursively calls `AhrensAverage(TimeSeries, period)` when the `else` clause is executed. Inevitably, the same function with the same parameters is called infinitely often.

Comment: Thank you both for taking your time & helping me!

Comment: I misinterpreted the original code. It doesn't use a recursive function as I thought. Anyways, thank you. In case anyone else is looking for Ahrens Moving Average, I'll provide my code.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is looking for Ahrens Moving Average, this is my code:

```
def AhrensMovingAverage(source, period):
    afr = []
    for index, rows in source.iterrows():
        if index < Period:
            afr.append(rows)
        else:
            afr.append(afr[-1] + ((rows.iloc[-1] - ((afr[-1]+ afr[-Period]) / 2)) / Period))
    return afr
```